# Inserting select query results from source table into derived table

Tags: mysql

My problem is populating my last two columns in the derived_daily table (which is derived from the source table, prices_daily).

(source table) **prices_daily:**

```
sequence        INT(11)         NO    PRI  AUTO_INCREMENT
symbol          VARCHAR(6)      NO    MUL
date            DATE            NO    MUL
high            DECIMAL(8,2)    YES
low             DECIMAL(8,2)    YES
close_adj       DECIMAL(8,2)    YES
```

(target table) **derived_daily:**

```
symbol           VARCHAR(6)     YES
date             DATE           NO
mov_avg10        DECIMAL(8,2)   YES
std_dev10        DECIMAL(8,2)   YES
range_daily      DECIMAL(8,2)   YES
range_std_dev30  DECIMAL(8,2)   YES
```

I can populate the first 4 columns with the code below:

```
INSERT INTO derived_daily(symbol, date, mov_avg10, std_dev10)
(
SELECT t1.symbol, t1.date, AVG(t2.close_adj) AS mov_avg10, STDDEV(t2.close_adj) 
           AS std_dev10 
FROM prices_daily t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN prices_daily t2 
    ON t2.symbol = t1.symbol AND (t1.sequence - t2.sequence)BETWEEN 0 AND 9 
    WHERE t1.symbol = 'C' GROUP BY t1.date
) ;
```

but when I try to populate the 'range_daily' in the derived table with this:

```
INSERT INTO derived_daily(symbol, date, range_daily)
(
SELECT t2.symbol, t2.date, (high - low) AS range_daily 
FROM prices_daily t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN derived_daily t2 
    ON t2.symbol = t1.symbol AND t2.date = t1.date 
    WHERE t2.symbol = 'C' 
    ORDER BY t2.date
) ;
```

It places it in the correct column, but at the bottom of the table in new rows instead of the existing rows w/ the missing data (range_daily and eventually, range_std_dev30). I've tried a number of tweaks and am getting mostly "ERROR 1364, field 'date' doesn't have a default value. I want to populate the last 2 columns to match with what I've already placed in the table (same rows), not new ones at the bottom.

I've spent a long time looking at related questions/answers, but still can't relate to my issue (noob...apologies).Any help/advice/etc. would be greatly appreciated! P.S. working on formatting the question appropriately, but had to come to the main place (this site is the top) as I'm getting frustrated lol.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I've been told to use UPDATE on the remaining rows, but unsure how to populate the rows all at once in the column using the UPDATE...SET...WHERE syntax since I need to JOIN the two tables to establish values for 'range_daily'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an UPDATE of existing rows, rather than INSERT of new rows.

For example:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT t1.symbol
              , t1.date
              , AVG(t2.close_adj) AS mov_avg10
              , STDDEV(t2.close_adj) AS std_dev10
           FROM prices_daily t1
           LEFT
           JOIN prices_daily t2
             ON t2.symbol = t1.symbol
            AND (t1.sequence - t2.sequence) BETWEEN 0 AND 9
          WHERE t1.symbol = 'C'
          GROUP
             BY t1.symbol
              , t1.date
       ) s
  JOIN derived_daily t
    ON t.symbol = s.symbol
   AND t.date = s.date
   SET t.mov_avg10 = s.mov_avg10
     , t.std_dev10 = s.std_dev10
```

For testing, you can replace the `UPDATE` keyword with `SELECT t.symbol, t.date, t.mov_avg10, t.std_dev10, s.mov_avg10, s.std_dev10 FROM` and remove the `SET` clause at the end. That will list the rows from t that will be updated, with the existing values in the row, and the new values that will be assigned.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

To get all of the columns inserted, you could combine three queries.
This is a monster query, but once we break it down into its components it kind of makes sense.

```
INSERT INTO derived_daily
( symbol
, `date`
, mov_avg10
, std_dev10
, range_daily
, range_std_dev30
)
SELECT q.symbol
     , q.date
     , q.mov_avg10
     , q.std_dev10
     , r.range_daily
     , s.range_std_dev30
  FROM ( SELECT t1.symbol
              , t1.date
              , AVG(t2.close_adj) AS mov_avg10
              , STDDEV(t2.close_adj) AS std_dev10
           FROM prices_daily t1
           LEFT
           JOIN prices_daily t2
             ON t2.symbol = t1.symbol
            AND (t1.sequence - t2.sequence) BETWEEN 0 AND 9
          WHERE t1.symbol = 'C'
          GROUP BY t1.symbol, t1.date
       ) q
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t3.symbol
              , t3.date
              , (t3.high - t3.low) AS range_daily
           FROM prices_daily t3
          WHERE t3.symbol = 'C'
       -- GROUP BY t3.symbol, t3.date
       ) r
    ON r.symbol = q.symbol
   AND r.date = q.date
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t4.symbol
              , t4.date
              , STDDEV(d.range_daily) AS range_std_dev30
           FROM prices_daily t4
           LEFT
           JOIN ( SELECT t5.symbol
                       , t5.date
                       , (t5.high - t5.low) AS range_daily
                    FROM prices_daily t5
                   WHERE t5.symbol = 'C'
                -- GROUP BY t5.symbol, t5.date
                ) d
             ON d.symbol = t4.symbol
            AND d.date >= t4.date
            AND d.date <= t4.date + INTERVAL -30 DAY
          WHERE t4.symbol = 'C'
          GROUP BY t4.symbol, t4.date
       ) s
    ON s.symbol = q.symbol
   AND s.date = q.date
 ORDER BY q.date, q.symbol
```

---

That query is essentially of the form

```
INSERT INTO target
SELECT q.key
     , q.val
     , r.val
     , s.val
  FROM q
  LEFT
  JOIN r ON r.key = q.key
  LEFT
  JOIN s ON s.key = q.key
```

This assumes that `(symbol,date)` is unique on the (source) `prices_daily` table, and will also be unique on the (target) `derived_daily` table.

For testing, we can run the queries that supply the values from q, r and s separately.

I took a shot at the formula for range_std_dev30... STDDEV on the range value from the current date and back 30 days.

(I'm a little bothered by the use of the use of the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence to derive the past 10 rows... we don't usually rely on a guarantee that the auto_increment id values will be sequential with no gaps. That's something we observe, but is not guaranteed behavior, especially if rows are inserted in a different sequence.

(For the 30 days, i used a date range comparison.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, spencer (and the formatting, I need to work on that!). So to UPDATE the last two columns in 'derived_daily', I need another JOIN (for 'range_daily'), will this work in your above code? Then use the script again for the 'range_std_dev30' like above, except using the 'derived_daily' as the LEFT JOIN table? Thanks again...can't wait until I know what I'm doing as you guys/gals on here are exceptional. PS, what does the "s" mean after the )? I see that on a lot of my searches and don't understand (sometimes it's "x" or whatever)...thanks!

Comment: @haddix: the "trick" is to write a SELECT statement that returns rows from the target table (i usually use an alias **`t`** for target), along with the JOIN to other tables (or inline view queries) that supply the values to be assigned, along with a unique identifier you can use to "match" to rows in the target table. Once you have that, you can replace the `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE` and add an appropriate `SET t.col = expression` clause.  That expression can be a simple reference to a column from the source, or it can include a conditional test e.g. `=IF(s.col>t.col,s.col,t.col)`

Comment: Awesome. So, to update the last two columns, I won't have to list all 6 in the field (that's where my dilemma started...could only do 4 in the initial statement). I'm still a bit confused w/ your explanation, but I think that's on me to study/research as I know this shouldn't be terribly difficult. Thank you for your time/help and detailed explanation.

Comment: sorry...the "s" after the ) is just an "s" and should be there, or is it short for something that needs to be written? Apologies for not putting this in earlier.

Comment: @haddix: the "**`s`**"  is an alias assigned to that inline view. When that query inside those parens runs, MySQL creates a temporary MyISAM table to hold the result, and MySQL requires a name to assign to that derived table. It doesn't have to specifically be "**`s`**", I choose s as shorthand for "source") it can be any valid identifier (that is, follows the rules for a table name) that doesn't conflict with another identifier in the statement. Think of that "**`s`**" as the tablename assigned to the rows returned by the query). We use that as a qualifier for column names.

Comment: hmmm, i ran your statement and got an empty table...does the fact I'm using InnoDB matter? Just read what you said and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Try running just the query inside the parens. That should be the key columns, and the new values to assign to the columns in the target table. (The query inside the parens should be a very close match to a query you had in the original question.) This query is expecting to find matching rows already in the target table, populated by the previous insert statement.

Comment: @haddix... (the rules say we're supposed to avoid extended chat.)  but i think i see the problem now, i wrote an UPDATE in place of the original insert, rather than for the subsequent.  i think a better approach is to get all the columns in one shot, and do the insert.  i'll get that statement together for you, and post a followup in my answer. (i apologize for not getting this right the first time, but i will persist until you get an answer that works for you.)

Comment: Yeah I can't chat yet (new guy)...thank you so much for the help, will check back!

Comment: That's what I was trying, but was getting lost in the sauce. Well done , would rep if I could! See you on the forum!

Comment: @haddix: it's with these types of queries that my unconventional formatting of SQL makes the SQL understandable, or at least decipherable.

Comment: 30 day doesn't work, am I going to get in trouble for the long discussion? I have no way to communicate since this is my first q?

Comment: ....think this is it AND d.date >= t4.date + INTERVAL -29 DAY
            AND d.date <= t4.date

Comment: @spencer7593...range_std_dev30 doesn't work for monthly. Getting 0.00 for lots of fields? If you can help, cool, if not thanks for getting me started.

Comment: I think the `>=` and `<=` comparison operators are reversed on the compare of d.date to the date range,  should be >= date - 29 day and should be <= date